# Why does removing head of list cause segfault here?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have a simple linked list structure using void* as my data type. I have verified adding pointers to int values and logging the results, however attempting to remove the head node is causing a segfault. My List definition is as follows:

```
struct List
{
    void* data;
    struct List* next;

    void* (*add)(struct List* list, size_t size, void* value);
    struct List* (*delete_node)(struct List* list, struct List* node);
    void* (*get_unsafe)(struct List* list);
    void (*print)(struct List* list);
    void (*destroy)(struct List* list);

};

struct List* 
List_construct()
{
    struct List* l = (struct List*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct List));

    l->add = add;
    l->delete_node = delete_node;
    l->get_unsafe = get_unsafe;
    l->print = print;
    l->destroy = destroy;

    return l;
}

static void* 
add(struct List* list, size_t size, void* value)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: List provided to List_add is NULL\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (value == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: value provided to List_add is NULL ref\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (size == 0)
    {
        printf("Error: size provided to List_add is zero\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    void* data = malloc(size);
    memccpy(data, value, 1, size);

    if (!list->data)    // this is an empty list
    {
        list->data = data;
        return data;
    }

    while(list->next)
    {
        list = list->next;
    }

    struct List* n_ptr = (struct List*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct List));
    n_ptr->data = data;
    list->next = n_ptr;

    return value;
}

static void
destroy(struct List* l)
{
    if (l == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: attempting dispose a NULL list\n");
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        free(l->data);
        l->data = NULL;
        struct List* tmp = l->next;
        free(l);
        l = NULL;
        l = tmp;

    } while(l);
}
```

This is the function I am calling assigned to the function pointer in the struct above. I am aware the function will only remove the head as it stands in the example, I removed all the other logic whilst I am reasoning about this error.

```
static struct List*
delete_node(struct List* list, struct List* node)
{
    if (list == node)
    {
        list = list->next;

        free(node->data);
        free(node);
    }

    return list;
}
```

My logs to verify that values were added:

```
[Start of List debug]
    List Entry [0]: address: 0x16c6150 data: 0x16c6170 next: 0x16c6598
    List Entry [1]: address: 0x16c6598 data: 0x16c6588 next: 0x16c65c8
    List Entry [2]: address: 0x16c65c8 data: 0x16c65b8 next: (nil)
[End of List debug]
```

This call in main causes the segfault:

```
l = l->delete_node(l, l);
```

Comment: Please post a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment we can't how you create list nodes

Comment: You don't need both `return list;` statements in the function; the second is sufficient.  If the code is crashing, there is no protection in the code against either `list` or `node` being null pointers.  It isn't clear that you've passed a null pointer to the function, but it also isn't clear that you haven't.  It also isn't clear how you remove the node from the list when it isn't the first item in the list — surely you need to find the element in the list where `ptr->next == node` so that you can set `ptr->next = node->next;` to remove the item from the list but leave an intact list.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: MCRE is an interesting acronym.  The official name used to be MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example — [mcve]) and is now officially MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example — [mre]) — the links should go to the same place that you linked to, even though I type MCVE and MRE inside square brackets to generate the URLs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh yes... I somwhow must have had 'mcve' in mind and somehow mixed it up with the requirement 'complete' :-)

Comment: `add()` looks suspicious: as there is no size passed the function can only store the pointer itself in the node it creates. So it's up to the caller to allocate a buffer for `value` and pass that buffer

Comment: Does `if (list == node)` indicates that the **l** in the function and expression `l = l->delete_node(l, l)` is freeing itself? Could that be a problem?

Comment: I've just noticed when logging the addresses of my node, that on the 2nd line, the data address is before that of the node address which seems a bit odd to me